# How to loop cut a plan surface

Tags: faces

If we take a circle not a sphere and not a cylinder. A circle with 32 edges and make face with F and i want to divide that faces in 6 equal parts.  As Loop cut do not work on faces. How can we make it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a nice example of a very unclear question. I actually got it completely different than the other two, as I had a piece of cake in mind like this:

[image: sliceDisc]

You'll need 36 verts for this to work, and have the disc filled with an n-gon. Then, connecting the vertices opposite each other using <kbd>J</kbd> would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

1. Inset <kbd>I</kbd> the circle with distance of `1.0/6` units (if the circle has radius of `1.0`).
2. Repeat 4x with *Repeat Last* <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

   [image]

---

If the circle has some ugly diameter:

1. Select single radius edge.
2. Invert selection <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and delete edges.
3. Subdivide the edge with <kbd>W</kbd> > Subdivide. Set number of cuts.
4. Spin the divided edge into circle with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. Set 360° and 32 steps.
5. Remove doubles.

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Delete the central vertex, select all 32 edges, E extrude, S scale, move the mouse, enter to confirm. repeat 6 times; select the last 32 scaled edges, Alt M merge at center to close the mesh. After pressing S for scaling you can enter a numeric value for scaling exactly the same amount every time.